# Add reference a class library to a portable class library xamarin

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, class-library

i have a problem that i want to add an ordinary class library to a portable class library in Xamarin. The VS2015 community says that i can only add reference portable class library to another portable class library. So i want to ask if there is a possibility that i can add ordinary to portable library or convert it to PCL. Thanks in avance.
[explanation in VS2015 community](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAcwh.png)

Comment: What's in this 'ordinary' class library, and do you have the source? If you have the source and it has nothing that is platform specific then you could re-compile it as a PCL. If it is something with platform specifics such as Windows API calls then it won't work.

Comment: in my case, this is just a normal class library that i want to add to a PCL. And my scenario is that i want to reference a WCF service to my projet xamarin forms. In fact, i know we can do it with (Silverlight Service Outil) SlSvcoutil, but Silverlight generate only async operation, but what i want is sync operation, so i want to add reference class library to my portable class library

Comment: a PCL can only reference other PCL that target the same profile.